# Blinking in taskbar with color change

Tags: wpf-controls

This is similar to the "Blinking Browser Application in taskbar".
It has been mentioned that "Title" ought to be changed to have a blinking effect. But there is nothing mentioned about color change. 
Is it not window's own property to blink with the usual "orange" color if title or anything is changed? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

https://web.archive.org/web/20120716063324/http://www.bobpowell.net/flashbar.htm - I found out the solution for my question.

Many others have written like the one found in this blog.